# WHERE clause not working in inner-join query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, inner-join

Can anyone please tell me if I put the where clause on the wrong part of my query?

```
$year = $this->input->post('yearFilter');
$month = $this->input->post('monthFilter');
$day = $this->input->post('dayFilter');
$building = $this->input->post('buildingFilter');
$fulldate = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
$query = "select * from payments inner join $building on payments.stallnum=$building.stallNum where payments.paymentdate='$fulldate'";
$run = $this->db->query($query)->result();
return $run;
```

Comment: Could you add your expected result and some example for test?

Comment: Well, what happens when you *run this code*?  Do you get the expected results?  Different results?  An error?  Instead of having us *guess*, why don't you tell us the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The query is the right syntax:

```
select * 
from payments 
inner join $building 
on payments.stallnum=$building.stallNum 
where payments.paymentdate='$fulldate'
```

However, in your `WHERE` clause I have a feeling you are looking for a payment date that is literally equal to the string `$fulldate`. Try concatenating your string for the query differently.

Comment: Please mark as Accepted with the Green check mark. That is how we roll here @john